# How to find an X capacitor

Tags: x-capacitor

Working from a data sheet reference design a 47nF/X 250V capacitor is recommended.

What makes a capacitor an X capacitor? From some googling i've found that X capacitors are meant to go across mains. From some vague references they are metalized film capacitors because they are self healing.

Would any metalized film capacitor be an X capacitor as long as the voltage rating is met or exceeded, or is there some other specific rating that officially makes it an X capacitor?

Would a data sheet specifically say "X" capacitor or is there some other subtle way that it would be listed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The datasheet has to say "X capacitor" in pretty large letters on the first page. You shouldn't be inferring the X-rating from electrical specs. (Same for Y-rating, while we're at it.)

Some additional background on X- and Y-capacitors can be found [here (presentation slides as PDF)](http://www.kemet.com/Lists/Filestore/EvoxRifaRFIandSMD.pdf) and [here](https://electrosome.com/x-and-y-rated-capacitors/).